# How to unpack .rar file in Python?

Tags: python, macos, archive, rar, unrar

I have a problem in unpacking .rar files in Python. I am using macOS, with Anaconda Navigator and Spyder IDE.
I have already installed `unrar`, `pyunpack`, `py7zr`, `rarfile`, `patool` packages. However, when I run this code:

```py
import zipfile

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from rarfile import RarFile
import patoolib
from pyunpack import Archive

# Archive('aaa.rar').extractall(".")
patoolib.extract_archive('aaa.rar')
```

I get the error message:

```
PatoolError: could not find an executable program to extract format rar; candidates are (rar,unrar,7z),
```

and

```
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/patoolib/__init__.py", line 684, in extract_archive
    return _extract_archive(archive, verbosity=verbosity, interactive=interactive, outdir=outdir, program=program)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/patoolib/__init__.py", line 470, in _extract_archive
    program = find_archive_program(format, 'extract', program=program)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/patoolib/__init__.py", line 336, in find_archive_program
    raise util.PatoolError("could not find an executable program to %s format %s; candidates are (%s)," % (command, format, ",".join(programs)))
```

Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: What happens when you open a shell and run `unrar`? And if you try the same from within the Anaconda environment? The issue is that `patoolib` can't find the `unrar` executable. It's either not installed, isn't on your PATH, or isn't findable from within the Anaconda environment.

Comment: If I type 'unrar' from the Terminal, then it shows me info about the commands that I can use (extract files, list archive content, ... ). If I type 'unrar' from within the Anaconda environment, then it shows me 'NameError: name 'unrar' is not defined'

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rarfile](https://rarfile.readthedocs.io/index.html) module

```
import rarfile

rf = rarfile.RarFile("myarchive.rar")
for f in rf.infolist():
    print(f.filename, f.file_size)
    if f.filename == "README":
        print(rf.read(f))
```

Comment: This doesn't extract the files, it only prints the name of the files inside the .rar.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `unrar` (and other programs you've installed locally) are not findable by Anaconda from within an Anaconda environment. The solution is to install them within that environemtn.

---

From within your Anaconda environment,

```sh
conda install unrar
```

will make `unrar` available, and make Python packages like `patoolib` that depend on it work.

---

Conda also provides a [conda package](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/7zip) for handling .rar files, which can be installed with

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge 7zip
```

---

More information on Conda environments can be found [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/environments.html). In particular they say one of the benefits of a Conda environment is that it "Manages non-Python dependencies (R, Perl, arbitrary executables).", of which `unrar` is an arbitrary executable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I successfully installed unrar from within Anaconda environment (typing 'conda install unrar'), but unfortunately it still doesn't work and the error is the same of before